# Node.js mongoose performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there somebody that has experience using mongoose.js as Node.js mapper for Mongodb at high scale?

I am wondering if I should use the native driver, so I keep everything lightweight or to write a simple wrapper.

If anybody got some tips, advise thank you very much.

Comment: Pretty sure mongoose uses the native driver under the hood.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html

Comment: It does, and mongoose also makes it easy to directly use native calls when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really need an ORM\ODM I recommended you don't use Mongoose at all.

It seems most people (including me, briefly) are you using Mongoose because the native driver's api is to cluncky and difficult to understand.

That's why I have switch to [mongojs](https://github.com/gett/mongojs).
Mongojs is a module that wraps the native driver but with much cleaner api that is almost identical to mongo shell.

I can't really comment on the scalability of Mongoose but mongojs is just that, a lightweight wrapper around the native driver.

Comment: Can you back this up with real world problems scaling Mongoose, or is it just based on it not being a light wrapper for the driver? From what I understand Trello is a huge node.js app in production using Mongoose and it performs well enough for them. There are a lot of great features in Mongoose (middleware, plugins, virtuals, strict schema definition, related document population to name a few) which save development time - it's not just replacing a clunky driver api. Losing that for real performance gains is fine, but what research is your position based on?

Comment: Sorry for the -1, but this is IMO an non-answer - the OP asked for performance and scalability details and you provided none, just said you used to use it but not any more - no reasoning or objective information. You say 'That's why I have switch to mongojs' - but you don't explain *why* at all.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party some but according to [this article](https://medium.com/@bugwheels94/performance-difference-in-mongoose-vs-mongodb-60be831c69ad) Mongoose performs worse compared to the native MongoDB Node.js client.
More or less Mongoose is slower (ops/sec) for every single metric collected (queries and inserts).

Source code with the benchmarks can be found [here](https://github.com/bugwheels94/mongoose-vs-mongodb)

Comment: Useful link, that is why I upvoted your answer.